# Why is the "if" not executed within a loop?

Tags: c++

The `cout << "Fin"`, it is never executed

```
int main(){
    int num, suma=0, divisor=0;
    
    cout<<"Escribe un número"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    cout<<num<<": ";
    while(divisor<num){
        if(num % divisor==0){
            cout<<divisor;
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"Fin";
```

Comment: Try inputting `-1`, and `cout << "Fin"` will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num % divisor` with `divisor=0` does *division by zero*, which typically leads to aborting.

You should give another initial value (maybe `1` or `2` looks good, depending on the purpose) to that.

Also, as @KfirVentura pointed out, you should update `divisor` (or `num`) in the loop, or the loop will run infinitely if `divisor<num` initially becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

"if" loop would not run as divisor is 0 and for all conditions will give a runtime exception error, which is apparent. Try changing the value of divisor.